# Multiple Joins using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing my first PySpark project, and I need a little help please.

The project is like this: I have 10 different data sources, and I created from each of them an sql query to get a data structure that looks like that:

```
A - UserID, fieldA, fieldB
B - UserID, fieldC
C - UserID, fieldD, fieldE, fieldF
D - UserID, fieldG, fieldH
......
```

My question is how to join all these data-sets together (FULL OUTER), all on the same key - UserID, so my end result will look like this:

```
UserID, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD, .....
```

Comment: Not all users exists in all data-sets! Theres a chance A has 5 users, B has 100 users and C has 20 users (that neither of them exists in A or B).

Not sure what's the best/easiest way to do it - either using Spark SQL functions or spark.sql(SQL Query) - but every help will be great!

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write serveral `join`s :

```
df_A.join(
    df_B,
    on="UserID",
    how="full"
).join(
    df_C,
    on="UserID",
    how="full"
).join( ... )
```

If you want it to be more compact, you could probably do something like :

```
from functools import reduce

joined_df = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.join(
            b,
            on="UserID",
            how="full"
        )
    ),
    [df_A, df_B, df_C .... ]
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer! but - not all users exists in all data-sets! Theres a chance A has 5 users, B has 100 users and C has 20 users (that neither of them exists in A or B). in your example all joins are on a.UserID, so if B+C has a user that wasn't in A - it won't be in the final join...

Comment: @Bramat No, it creates a first dataframe with only one column userid which contains all data from A and B, then another dataframe wich contains (A + B) + C, etc .... at the end, you will have all your ids, that is the principal of full joins